# C# + google drive: загрузка файла на сервер

Tags: c#, google-drive

Пишу приложение, нужно загружать файла на google drive и получать ссылку на скачивание для загруженного файла. Пробовал писать по гугловским мануалам,но при загрузке файла вылезает ошибка авторизации. В интеренте вообще мало инфы по данной теме.

Пример, по которому я делал тут:  https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs#step_1_enable_the_drive_api

Собственно, код скопирован, изменены лишь параметры учетки(ClientId, ClientSecret).
ошибка вылетает на:

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "CLIENT_ID_HERE",
        ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE",
     },
     new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
     "user",
     CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

Текст ошибки:

> aggregateexception was unhandled by user code

Буду благодарен как за советы, так и за ссылки на толковый материал.

Comment: Стандартный комментарий: покажите код (pastebin.com в помощь), место, в котором возникает ошибка, код и текст ошибки.

Comment: `AggregateException` содержит в себе набор других исключений. Загляните отладчиком внутрь, добавьте в вопрос эти самые исключения.

Comment: @VladD, вечер добрый. Да я вчера тоже самое по мануалу делал: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs#step_1_enable_the_drive_api

Если не верите - могу все заскринить.

Comment: @z668: Если то, что вы говорите — правда, это означает жЫрный баг в гугловской библиотеке: если библиотека нужна, без неё не должно собираться вовсе. Сообщите им, пускай чинят. Напишите нам о результатах, хорошо?

Comment: Уже поправили, сейчас бага не наблюдается, но вчера был.

Comment: Хотя нет, вру))) Совсем про тоекен забыл. Удалил токен и воспроизвел баг. Сейчас на ютьюб залью для наглядности.

Comment: @VladD Пожалуйста: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4JeS2YivyY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @z668: Хм. Вижу. Поставил вам +1. Мне кажется, имеет смысл сообщить гуглу об ошибке (там в конце страницы с документацией есть ссылка «report an issue»), пусть чинят. (У меня нету экаунта, не могу проверить ссылку.)

Answer (score 1):

Может быть не совсем вовремя, но решение данной проблемы в отсутствии либы в референсес:

> Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.16\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll

Update: Всем неверующим (тем кто ставит минусы посвящается):  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4JeS2YivyY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Без референса проект не соберется вовсе

Comment: Я уверен в том, о чем говорю! Вчера была абсолютно такая же проблема! За что -1? Вы проверяли вообще? Собирали под .NET 4.5?

Comment: @VladD Благодарю, сейчас как раз пишу им. Оставлю почту для связи, если ответят - выложу сюда.

Comment: @VladD Я весь проект под снос пущу, не только CLIENT_SECRET.